# Dynamically changing the template for an Angular 4 components

Tags: angular, angular2-template, angular2-components

Using Angular 4.1, I'm trying to dynamically change a module type's template before the module rendered.  Is this possible?

We are bootstrapping an unknown number of components on the page (from a known list of component types), and the page may contain multiple components of the same type.  I've found out a way to give each of these components a different selector so they can be rendered separately (even if they're of the same type), but I also need to give each one a different template.  **The template should be the inner HTML of the selected element.**

Here's the code:

```
import { Component, NgModule, Inject, ApplicationRef, ComponentFactoryResolver, OpaqueToken, Type } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { MyNavComponent } from './MyNav.component';
import { MyRotatorComponent } from './MyRotator.component';
import { MySignUpComponent } from './MySignUp.component';

export const BOOTSTRAP_COMPONENTS_TOKEN = new OpaqueToken('bootstrap_components');

@NgModule({
    imports: [BrowserModule],
    declarations: [
        MyNavComponent,
        MyRotatorComponent,
        MySignUpComponent
    ],
    entryComponents: [
        MyNavComponent,
        MyRotatorComponent,
        MySignUpComponent
    ],
    providers: [
        {
            provide: BOOTSTRAP_COMPONENTS_TOKEN,
            useValue: [
                { type: MyNavComponent },
                { type: MyRotatorComponent },
                { type: MySignUpComponent }
            ]
        },
    ]
})
export class AppModule {
    constructor(
        private resolver: ComponentFactoryResolver,
        @Inject(BOOTSTRAP_COMPONENTS_TOKEN) private components: [Component],
    ) { }
    ngDoBootstrap(appRef: ApplicationRef) {
        console.log(this.components);
        this.components.forEach((componentDef: { type: Type<any>, selector: string }) => {
            const factory = this.resolver.resolveComponentFactory(componentDef.type);
            let selector = factory.selector;
            let nodes = document.querySelectorAll(selector);
            for (let i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++) {
                let node = nodes[i];
                (<any>factory).factory.selector = node;

                //The next line doesn't work... how can I dynamically set the template?
                (<any>factory).factory.template = node.innerHTML;

                appRef.bootstrap(factory);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

As noted near the end of the above code, `(<any>factory).factory.template = node.innerHTML;` doesn't work.  I've also tried modifying the metadata for the type, but that doesn't work, either.

Is what I'm trying to achieve possible by another means?  If not, is this worth submitting as a feature request?

(Note: the above code is based in part on the code of others at https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/7136.)

## Update:

I'm wondering if in a future update of Angular I'll be able to achieve the same result by setting the template to `<ng-content></ng-content>` to include the innerHTML of the selected element.  This isn't possible now with bootstrapped components, but based on this [issue on Git](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/4946#ref-issue-209742777), I'm hopeful it will be soon.

Comment: Are you using AOT? More precisely, are you going to ship `@angular/compiler` to production?

Comment: @yurzui I'm just getting a hang of the new Angular and haven't set up AOT compilation yet, but I think that using AOT would be ideal eventually.  Does this change anything?  Would I be able to pull this off if I stuck with JIT?

Comment: I may not have understand all the detail of your question, but I think you could achieve what you want with the use of `*ngFor` and `*ngSwitch` structural directive.
with the `ngFor`, you loop for the total number of component you need.
with the `ngSwitch`, you can then freely choose between the known set of components depending of some variable.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You cannot set a template for a component factory after it was created. Angular compiler parses templates when generating a factory and creates a view class for each component. After the component factory and its view class are created you cannot modify it. In your example you're using `ComponentFactoryResolver`

```
const factory = this.resolver.resolveComponentFactory(componentDef.type);
```

which returns already created factory.

The only option is to change the template before the compiler generates factories. But I don't think it's possible. You will probably have to take a look at the dynamic generation of components.

Read  [Here is what you need to know about dynamic components in Angular](https://hackernoon.com/here-is-what-you-need-to-know-about-dynamic-components-in-angular-ac1e96167f9e) for more information.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation and helpful article, @Maximus.  What you're saying makes sense.  I'm going to hang on to hope for a while that there's another way of achieving this before marking your solution as the answer and closing the door on the idea of bootstrapped components having dynamic templates.

Comment: Sure, no problem. Templates have to be compiled by the compiler anyway. If you have a compiled template, then you can use it for different purposes. You can get compiled templates with the `ng-template` directive. But I'm not sure this solution will work in your case.

Comment: Just as a point of clarification - let's say I have a `component.ts` file and want to have multiple different view templates for it (i.e. `component.1.html` and `component.2.html`) - what you're saying is that it is not possible to programmatically choose which view template to use?

Comment: You will need to dynamically create a component class.  Read the article I referenced