# Angular Multiple Templates - With Multiple Components

Tags: angular

i would like to make a Multiple Template scenario but i need your guidance :( ,
in this scenario User can change the whole template,
it's means User can change Template <1> to Template <2> , Template <3> , etc.
so in each Template we have specific layout and elements (components).

something like this (example):

```
App
    - Template 1
            - Home
            - About
            - Blog

    - Template 2
            - Home
            - About
            - Blog
```

etc.

so user can easily switch between Templates(layouts) in his/her profile by clicking on "Changing Template" drop down.

** Restful API Backend is ready and User has schema like this **

```
User {
    _id,
    username,
    password,
    template,
    etc....
}
```

thanks a lot

Comment: This answer might be useful https://stackoverflow.com/a/44277384/6787953

Comment: What kind of template you have? is it just some color changing or something?

Comment: @meshkati it's not only css , it's also HTML and layouts.

Comment: @JohnDoe Actually you have many options to do it. If you wanna provide separate files and logics for each template, you can make multiple components and then choose the proper one when the app starts, with factories. Or in a simple way, just write a single component and use directives like ng-if to decide how to show an element based on the layout the user selected.

Comment: @meshkati i'm new in angular , so should i read about "factories" ? thanks

Comment: @JohnDoe Not neccessarly, I recomment you to implement the behaviour you want with just the directives like ng-if. Imagine in your main-component you wanna display the component A to user who is on template A and display component B to user that is on template B, you can handle it with a service who knows the selected template of the user, and then user a `ng-if` to display each of the components base on the template the user selected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is there :
https://github.com/little-pinecone/angular-multi-layout-scaffolding
blog : http://keepgrowing.in/angular/apply-multi-layout-to-an-angular-app/