# How can I give a component a template dynamically?

Tags: angular

I am trying to make it so that a parent component can pass an optional template to a child component, and the child component will use that as its template or fall back to a default template...  Something like this:

```
# my.component.ts

import defaultTemplate from './template.html';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-component',
  template: '{{ dynamicTemplate }}'
)}
export class MyComponent implements OnInit {
   @Input() template: string;
   dynamicTemplate: string;

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.dynamicTemplate = this.template || defaultTemplate;
  }
}
```

```
# parent.component.ts

import templateA from './template-a.html';
import templateB from './template-b.html';

@Component({
  selector: 'parent-component',
  template: `
    <p>some fun dynamic templates...</p>
    <my-component [template]="templateA"></my-component>
    <my-component [template]="templateB"></my-component>
    <my-component></my-component>
  `
)}
export class ParentComponent {
  templateA: string;
  templateB: string;
  constructor() {
    this.templateA = templateA;
    this.templateB = templateB;
  }
}
```

Except this results in escaped html..  What is the proper way to do this?

Comment: could ng-content cover your requirement?

Comment: @kin it *could* except I can't figure out how to make it work in this context.  Every example I've seen is involving giving it `#refName` and having those in the main template.  Is there a way to just set inner-html on an ng-content reference?

Comment: I did something similiar recently, however instead of a component i made a structural directive. where i could set templates with template ref as parameters.  However i also had some conditions that needed to be set to make it work https://angular.io/guide/structural-directives

Answer (score 0):

**Old answer that is not OP is asking**

Not sure if I understood correctly, but would something like this work for you?

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-ngvgnd

basically

```
<my-component>
  <child-a></child-a>
</my-component>


<my-component>
  <child-b></child-b>
</my-component>


<my-component></my-component>
```

**Edited the code to handle the html as an input.**

```
import { Input, Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { DomSanitizer } from '@angular/platform-browser';

@Component({
  selector: 'actual-answer',
  template: `
  <h1>parent html code</h1>
  <div [innerHtml]="htmlString"></div>
  `,
})
export class ActualAnsweComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() yourHtml;
  htmlString;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.htmlString = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(this.yourHtml);
  }

  constructor(private sanitizer: DomSanitizer) {}
}
```

Comment: No, because the inner html needs to come from an `@input` on `my-component`

Comment: is this template being read from somewhere external? Is it static html or will it have bindings?

Comment: I updated the blitz to handle htmls, it wont work if you want/need bindings though

Comment: Yeah, it does need bindings, unfortunately.

Comment: Do you mind me asking what is the actual problem? This kinda looks like a XY problem

Comment: If you use angular material however I think you can achieve something like this with TemplatePortal

Answer (score 0):

As Patrick pointed out in the comments, it's possible to compile and ship the `JitCompilerFactory` with your application at the cost of 80kb. Then you can re-compile your components at runtime. Not sure if that works with the most recent versions though. https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/compiling-angular-templates-runtime-dima-slivin/

---

See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44277384/12914833.

Short answer is you can't. Angular compiles the components into scripts, so changing the template at run time isn't possible. If you're just trying to inject some html *into* a template at runtime, that's doable. I'd suggest something like [ngx-markdown](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-markdown) for that (see end of answer).

---

Having a template be generated from an input string is way too unpredictable anyway. You should define all possible states of the template. You can make it dynamic with input variables and directives like `ngIf`.

For example, you could make a few components `ComponentOne`, `ComponentTwo`, `ComponentThree` to represent three different templates. And then the dynamic component could look like:

```html
<app-component-one *ngIf="useComponentOne"></app-component-one>
<app-component-two *ngIf="useComponentTwo"></app-component-two>
<app-component-three *ngIf="useComponentThree"></app-component-three>
```

```js
export class DynamicComponent {
  @Input() useComponentOne = false;
  @Input() useComponentTwo = false;
  @Input() useComponentThree = false;
}
```

And to use it

```html
<app-dynamic-component [useComponentTwo]="true"></app-dynamic-component>
```

That makes the design much more predictable and testable.

---

If you just want to inject some html into a template, and you don't need it compiled with the component (ie. you're not trying to use angular directives or other components), ngx-markdown makes it easy.

```html
<markdown>{{ htmlString }}</markdown>
```

```js
export class MarkdownComponent {
  @Input() htmlString = "<h1>I'm an html header</h1>";
}
```

Comment: But... this was possible in angularJS, i.e. `element.append(compile(template)(scope));`..  How is one supposed to "upgrade" their app if things are not possible to do in the new version............ argh.

Comment: There is a way to inject an `ng-Template` into a component but I'm not exactly sure how to implement it. primeNg does it by using a custom `pTemplate` directive with a keyword. For example you can inject a template into the header and footer of this dialog: https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/dialog. Would an approach like that help? Not to be that guy but angular2 isn't really an upgrade of angularJS, it's a whole different framework.

Comment: It looks like I can accomplish what I want by following this: https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/compiling-angular-templates-runtime-dima-slivin/

Comment: Nice, just gotta compile the compiler.